# On button click focus input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to `autofocus` input on button click but it doesn't work. Code can be found here for edit: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPPCFP5RTU9E

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" autofocus>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Focus Input</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myText").autofocus = true;  
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`autofocus`is an HTML attribute. If you want to set the focus property by JavaScript you have to use `focus()`.

So try `document.getElementById("myText").focus();`:

**Working Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myText").focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" autofocus>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Focus Input</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```